# Gmail Automation via Bash (To refresh POP Fetch from other accounts)

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, curl, automation

Gmail has this option to fetch mails from other accounts. I used this feature to create a central mail box. Works good.

Gmail periodically polls other mail box over POP. But the frequency is 1 hour + , sometimes even more than that. There is no option to pull mails manually on mobile gmail version. But the full blow gmail web (not basic HTML Version) has has a REFRESH button on top which will fetch mails from other boxes right away. Also, under settings there is option to CHECK MAILS. Does the same.

Is there a way to automate a gmail login, click the REFRESH button and exit every 10 minutes?

I am comfortable with WGET, if it was a basic HTML, could have automated. But there is a lot of javascript processing before the page is loaded, and I am lost where to begin javascript automation via bash.

Any leads will help, Thanks.

Comment: "Where to begin javascript automation via bash." Don't. If you really want to run javascript headlessly, have a look at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or something similar. But bash is just the wrong language, because for things as complex as JS Bash can serve as nothing but a bridge, a glue of different tools, and there are just no one-stop tool that does this sort thing. In fact, I've yet to see a text-based browser that supports Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your input @4ae1e1